# conditionally loading external javascript libraries in my plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have written a plugin that depends on external libraries that I want to include conditionally, that is, the user can choose to not have them be included automatically in case the user's web site already has those libraries. Here is some pseudocode to illustrate the issue

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
PLUGIN.init({
    "param1": "foo",
    "parma2": 33, 
    "include": {"jquery": 0, "googlemaps": 0}
});
</script>
```

In my plugin script

```
var PLUGIN = {
    "init": function(obj) {
        if (obj.include.googlemaps !== 0) {
            document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&v=3.6">\x3C/script>');
        }

        if (obj.include.jquery !== 0) {
            document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js">\x3C/script>');
        }

        .. do more things ..
}
```

The problem is that when I am ready to "do more things," the libraries don't seem to be loaded yet. I get an error that jquery not found, or google maps not found. I can solve this by changing my code to

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&v=3.6">\x3C/script>');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js">\x3C/script>');

var PLUGIN = {
    "init": function(obj) {         
        .. do more things ..
}
```

but now the user can't control loading the libraries or not loading them. Suggestions? Workarounds?

**Update:** Thanks for the suggestions, you all, but no joy so far. Here is what I am doing, and what is happening. Since I am potentially loading 0 or more scripts (the user can optionally decide which scripts need not be loaded), I have made my code like so

```
"importLib": function(libPath, callback) {
    var newLib = document.createElement("script");

    if (callback !== null) {
        newLib.onload = callback;
    }
    newLib.src = libPath;

    document.head.appendChild(newLib);
},

"init": function(obj) {
    var scripts = [];
    if (obj.include.googlemaps !== 0) {
        scripts.push("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&v=3.6");
    }

    if (obj.include.jquery !== 0) {
        scripts.push("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js");
    }

    if (obj.include.anotherlib !== 0) {
        scripts.push("http://path/to/another/lib.js");
    }

    var len_scripts = scripts.length,
        callback = null;

    if (len_scripts > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < len_scripts; i++) {

            // add callback only on the last lib to be loaded
            if (i == len_scripts - 1) {
                callback = function() { startApp(obj) };
            }

            importLib(scripts[i], callback);
        }
    }

    // Start the app rightaway if no scripts need to be loaded
    else {
        startApp(obj);
    }
},

"startApp": function(obj) {
}
```

What happens is that Firefox croaks with a `attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope` error, and Safari doesn't get that error, but doesn't load anything. Funnily, Safari error console shows no error at all. Seems like the Firefox error is caused by the line `document.head.appendChild(newLib);` which, if I comment, the error goes away, but of course, the web page doesn't load correctly.

Comment: First, setting your callback on the last library in the list is not what you want: what if the first library comes from a really slow server?  It could load seconds after the last-listed script, after the callback has already fired.  You should use a counter that counts the number of requested libs.  Each time a lib loads, fire a callback that 1) decrements the counter and 2) starts the app if the counter is down to 0.

Comment: Second, try searching for that error text.  It looks like clearing your cache will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You should add each script as a DOM node and use the `onload` attribute to take action when it has completed loading.

```
function importLib(libPath, callback) {
    var newLib = document.createElement("script");
    newLib.onload = callback;
    newLib.src = libPath;
    document.head.appendChild(newLib);
}
```

Above, the `libPath` argument is the URL of the library, and the `callback` argument is a function to call when loading is complete.  You could use it as follows:

```
importLib("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js", function() {
   alert("jquery loaded!");
   nowDoSomething(aboutIt); 
});
```

By the way: in general, `document.write` is not a good solution for most problems (but I won't say *never* the right solution -- there are exceptions to every rule).

Comment: see update to original post (because formatting is not allowed in comments)

Answer (score 0):

the above solution would work in modern browsers but for IE 7/8 u might wanna added little extra code, something like this:

```
function importLib(libPath, callback) {
    var newLib = document.createElement("script");
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1) {
        newLib.onreadystatechange = function () {// this piece is for IE 7 and 8
           if (this.readyState == 'complete') {
              callback();
           }
        };
    } else {
        newLib.onload = callback;
    }
    newLib.src = libPath;
    document.head.appendChild(newLib);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. One workaround if you are writing your site in .NET is by conditionally writing the script reference before the page loads from the code behind.  My issue is when remote users access my app over VPN, it blocks access to the internet, thus google maps cannot be referenced.  This prevents the rest of the page from loading within a reasonable timeframe.  I tried controlling the  script reference of the google maps library via jQuery's getScript() command, but as you found out, the subsequent google maps configuration code runs before the external library is referenced.

My solution was to conditionally reference google maps from code behind instead:

VB (code behind):

```
'if VPN mode is not enable, add the external google maps script reference (this speeds up the interface when using VPN significantly)
    If Session("VPNMode") = False Then
        Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        sb.AppendLine("")
        sb.AppendLine("<script type='text/javascript'")
        sb.Append(" src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false'>")
        sb.Append("</script>")

        Dim header As LiteralControl = New LiteralControl
        header.Text = sb.ToString()
        Me.Page.Header.Controls.Add(header)
    End If
```

Client side script (javascript):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {

        if ($("input[name*='VPN']").is(":checked"))
        { }

        else {
            loadGoogleMap()
        }
    });
    function loadGoogleMap() {

        hazsite = new google.maps.LatLng(hazLat, hazLong);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), { zoom: 18, center: hazsite, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: hazsite,
            map: map,
            title: "Site Location"
        });
    }
</script>
```